# Modules: "Process moved to a different machine"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use google appengine modules to upload ~20k entities.

I have tried many methods to upload entities, I always get "Process moved to a different machine" and my module terminates. When I check my utilization, I see it has spiked Total CPU > 7170, so I increased the maximum instances to 5 (.yaml file below) and to thwart any memory issues I have increased the instance size to B4 (512MB). I have not configured any queue and I use the default queue without any changes to it.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
def PutInNDB_withEntityList(productList):
    someKeys = ndb.put_multi(productList)
```

and in my main function I call for every 200 entities

```
deferred.defer(PutInNDB_withEntityList, productList)
```

My modul.yaml file is configured as

```
application: dummyapp
module: modul
version: 3-2-jul27
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: B4
threadsafe: true

basic_scaling:
 max_instances: 5
 idle_timeout: 1m

builtins:
 - deferred: on

handlers:
 - url: /.*
script: somescript.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
version: "2.5.2"
```

How can I reliably store a large dataset (20K entities) into NDB datastore without the process being suddenly booted?

Comment: If all your doing is a put, why not simply use put_async in your main code? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async

Comment: put_multi_async or put_async also has same issue, same error.

Comment: Instead of running it in a deferred call simply run put_multi_async on the productList in your main function.

Comment: Thanks Bruyere, I did that put_multi_async also has same issue after a ~10k entities, memory starts blowing up https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9610 eventually I get "Process moved to a different machine"

Comment: There's a few things we can try here. First do you have to use 'NDB' ? 'NDB' uses memcache before sending it to the datastore. Can you try using db to put? Second, are you manually generated or do you allow GAE to generate your keys? If you use manually generate keys it can cause collision which will slow down the process. How big are your entities? Do they contain large amounts of data?

Comment: I started using NDB as google wants to move users to it, GAE generates my keys, entities are small <10kB. I will try db to put, and report back.

Comment: Any luck? Where did you see DB is being deprecated? DB is used to directly put entities into the datastore while NDB is for using memcahe and datastore at the same time. They are simply 2 different tools to be used in different situations. You can even use them both in the same code, only catch is knowing if the key is from NDB or DB  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic

Comment: I used db to upload, changed all my models to db and again same issue : "Process moved to a different machine" and then the instance just quits. This time memory usage was stable at 125-138MB. I suspect the issue is not with put or put_multi because I use a separate queue, it has more to do with querying one entity at a time. How do other people update all their entities (>20K) and one at a time?

Comment: Breaking up the query into batches. Pull lets say 100 entities into a list, update them, put_async, reset the list to a blank list then get the next bunch.

Comment: my query looks like this qry = appareldb.WomenApparel.all()
   qry = qry.filter('productId =', product.get('product_id'))         itemEntity = qry.get()   ; I am searching for a product by id updating it. put / put_multi does not seem to be an issue, the query is the problem! My entitity average size is only about 2kB, unfortunately i mix a projection query with "=" filter to reduce the size further on get

Comment: Resolved the problem, my module had this setting in the yaml file

'threadsafe = true'

For some reason the module was getting triggered twice (i use htmlout = urllib2.urlopen(modPath, timeout=5) from a GCE instance) and there were two instances of the same program running simultaneously.

Once 'threadsafe = false' was set, the error went away and module ran twice as fast.

Comment: Awesome glad you were able to track that down.

Answer (score 0):

Code Doesn't fit in the comments so here's what id do. You can easily adapt it to a task if you want

```
class DatastoreInfo(db.Model):
Cursor = db.StringProperty()
NumItemsProcessed = db.IntegerProperty()


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

qry = appareldb.WomenApparel.all()
    qry = qry.filter('productId =', product.get('product_id')) 

    dsInfo = DatastoreInfo.all().fetch(1)

    if(len(dsInfo) == 0):
        dsInfo = DatastoreInfo(NumItemsProcessed=0)
    else:
        dsInfo = dsInfo[0]
        qry.with_cursor(start_cursor=dsInfo.Cursor)

    itemIterator = qry.fetch(limit=500)
    if len(itemIterator) > 0:
        dsInfo.Cursor = empQuery.cursor()
        dsInfo.NumItemsProcessed += len(empIterator)
        dsInfo.put()
        for itemEntity in itemIterator:
            # Do work here

        db.put(itemIterator)
        self.redirect("/")
    else:
        dsInfo.delete()
          self.response.out.write(jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader("templates"), autoescape=True)
                            .get_template("index.html").render({"numItems":"Finished"}))
```

Comment: Neat way to process data in chunks.

Comment: Tried this method for larger chunks, with a B4 machine, this time it was the unexplained /_ah/stop after every chunk(~1K). I ran the script without the query and it worked fine.